# Conditionally formatting numbers using a \newcommand

Tags: macros, conditionals, ifthenelse, xifthen, renewcommand

I want to create a command the prints a number in red if its negative and green if it is positive.

I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
 
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\ifthenelse {#1 > 0} {\textcolor{PineGreen}{$#1$}} {\textcolor{red}{$#1$}}}
 
\begin{document}
\mynum{1.2} \mynum{-3.4}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work, as `ifthenelse` does not seem able to use the `#1`.

Any ideas about how to create the command I need?

Comment: tex numeric tests can only be on integers or lengths so not 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `ifthen` for such tests.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\ifdim#1pt>0pt\relax
  \textcolor{PineGreen}{$#1$}%
\else
  \textcolor{red}{$#1$}%
\fi
}
 
\begin{document}
\mynum{1.2} \mynum{-3.4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to play with very large numbers, consider using `xfp`.